# Combining SetDelayed, Set and Options

Tags: function-construction, options, assignment

- A function can be defined with `SetDelayed` while storing its value with `Set`, eg:

  ```
  f[x_] := f[x] = x
  ```

  Now, if the function is to have an optional argument with say default value `0`,

  ```
  f[x_,y_:0] := f[x,y] = x+y
  ```

  so `f[a]` equals `a` and `f[a,b]` equals `a+b`.
- Now we take it one step further and use Options instead of `y_:0`. So

  ```
  Options[g]={option1 -> 0}
  g[x_,OptionsPattern[]] := x + OptionValue[option1]
  ```

  works similarly to `f`, so `f[x,y]` equals `g[x, option1->y]` and `f[x]` equals `g[x]`
- But now comes the problem: how to use `Set` to store values of `g`, just like what was done for `f`?

  ```
  g[x_,OptionsPattern[]] := g[x, OptionsPattern[]] = x + OptionValue[option1]
  ```

  doesn't work, since it will store the first run of `g`, say `g[a, option1->b]` as `a+b`, but then `g[a]` will return `a+b`, as will `g[a, option1->c]`.

It makes sense. 
So how can this be done?

Comment: As you can see it is way more natural to memoize based on arguments rather than options. So why not stick to that?

Comment: I agree. But in this particular case, the goal is to make a larger function that calls other (many) functions, passing some options to those functions, but also allowing optional switches for saving output, etc. I can't store values in intermediate functions, as that would quickly run Mathematica out of memory (the computation takes several hours to run). So the point is to just store the final result in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following works as you intend:

```
Clear[g];
Options[g] = {option1 -> 0};
g[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 g[x, opts] = x + OptionValue[option1]
```

by assigning the options pattern an explicit name, we can use `Set` to produce an `DownValue` of `g` with that exact option pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make this work by introducing a function with a different name to do the memoization.  To be tidy, I'll limit the scope of the new name `gcache`

```
Options[g] = {option1 -> 0};
Module[{gcache},
 g[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := gcache[x, OptionValue[option1]];
 gcache[x_, a_] := gcache[x, a] = (Print["Evaluating"]; x + a)]
```

We only evaluate on the first call...

```
g[x, option1 -> b]
(* "Evaluating" *) 
(* b + x *)
```

...not the second...

```
g[x, option1 -> b]
(* b + x *)
```

... and `option1` is not cached...

```
g[a, option1 -> c]
(* "Evaluating" *)
(* a + c *)

g[a, option1 -> c]
(* a + c *)
```

Comment: Ended up accepting the other answer, as that was what I used. But I also benefited from yours. Thank you.